# what is equivalent of scale in opencv sift keypoint

Tags: c++, opencv, feature-detection, sift, keypoint

In my opencv project I try to compute sift features, I detect keypoints and compute descriptors. What I know it should contains 4 parameter: X, Y, Scale and Orientation. The opencv keypoint structure has pt (X, Y coordination) and angle (Orientation), but I could not understand where is the Scale parameter! can you explain me about this parameter?